# how to read second block in tfstate with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-remote-state

I have a remote state on s3 and i don't know how to access to the second block of the tfstate json file.

My tfstate looks like this:

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "terraform_version": "0.11.7",
    "serial": 1,
    "lineage": "79b7840d-5998-1ea8-2b63-ca49c289ec13",
    "modules": [
        {
            "path": [
                "root"
            ],
            "outputs": {},
            "resources": {},
            "depends_on": []
        },
        {
            "path": [
                "root",
                "vpc"
            ],
            "outputs": {
                "database_subnet_group": {
all my resources are listed here...
}
```

and I can access it this code:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "network" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "bakka-tfstate"
    key    = "global/network.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-1"
  }
}
```

but the output

```
output "tfstate" {
  value = data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs
}
```

shows me nothing

> Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
>
> Outputs:
>
> tfstate = {}

I believe it's because there's two json blocks in this tfstate and terraform read the first one which is empty, so i'm asking how to read the second one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only root outputs are accessible through remote state. This limitation is [documented here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html#root-outputs-only). It also suggests a solution - in the project that produces the state you're referring to, you will need to thread the output through to a root output.